# Managed metadata passing as a hashtable

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, development, ssom

Currently I am using the below code in order to create a new file with some metadata columns or update an existing one based on the `TargetLocationURL` variable.

```
using (Stream fs = File.OpenBinaryStream())
{
    Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
    ht.Add("vti_title", Metadata.Title);
    ht.Add("InternalFieldName1", Metadata.CalculatedFieldValue1);
    ht.Add("InternalFieldName2", Metadata.CalculatedFieldValue2);
    ht.Add("InternalFieldName3", Metadata.CalculatedFieldValue3);
    TargetFile = Folder.Files.Add(TargetLocationURL, fs, ht, true);
}
```

The fields that I have targeted above are in their majority a `Single line of text` type fields, which is fine and I can see that the item is created or updated accordingly (It took me a while to figure out which "title" name I should've used, since there is not much documentation on these fields but I managed it eventually).

The problem that I face is with some Managed Metadata columns that are linked to a Termset.

What is the correct format that I would have to implement in order to pass the Managed Metadata values throu the Hashtable?

I think I've tried every possible way of just copy-pasting the Managed Metadata value but the end result that I get is either the item is not updated with the new Managed Metadata values or the newly created item does not have its Managed Metadata Fields set accordingly(they appear as empty).

As a note, this Hashtable way has proven even difficult to Debug as I do not get any kind of exceptions after the `SPFileCollection.Add()` method.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try **-1;#{TermLabel}|{TermId}** format?. It should work

Comment: @Kalpesh Vaghela Hi, i tried that too but, unfortunately, it did not work.